# responsive issue jquery click slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a click slide that goes back and forward through the images,
But it doesnt scale or act responsive when on smaller window because obviously the width is set absolutely with pixels in the CSS and as the variable in my function.

If i change this I'm not sure how it'll work though as it slides back and forth the width of each img (607px)

Anyone got ideas?? Or a better way to do this??

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li class="slide"><img src="images/banner1.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
            <li class="slide"><img src="images/banner2.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
            <li class="slide"><img src="images/banner3.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
            <li class="slide"><img src="images/banner1.jpg" class="img-responsive"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#slider {
  width: 607px;
  height: 248px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slider .slides {
  display: block;
  width: 6000px;
  height: 248px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#slider .slide {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

JS:

```
(function() {

        var width = 607;
        var slideSpeed = 300;
        var currentSlide = 1;

        var $slider = $('#slider');
        var $slideContainer = $slider.find('.slides');
        var $slides = $slideContainer.find('.slide');

        var totalLength = $slides.length;

        $('#button-next').on('click', function(){
            $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width}, slideSpeed, function(){
                currentSlide++;
                if(currentSlide === $slides.length) {
                    currentSlide = 1;
                    $slideContainer.css('margin-left', '0');
                }
            });
        });

        $('#button-prev').on('click', function(){
            if(currentSlide === 1) {
                var pos = -1 * (width * ($slides.length -1));
                    $slideContainer.css('margin-left', pos);
                    $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '+='+width}, slideSpeed);
                    currentSlide = $slides.length - 1;
                } else {
                    $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '+='+width}, slideSpeed);
                        currentSlide--;
                    }

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make the slider you have posted responsive you will need to set your fixed dimensions in your CSS to fluid width.

Like this:

```
.slider {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}
.slider-frame {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
} 
.slide {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.control {
  width: 49%;
}
```

A wrote a very simple demo slider that hardly has any functionality just to serve the purpose of this explanation:

http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/aOLoYM

Resize your screen. The slides stay the width of the screen because the .slide and .slider are both set to 100% of the screens width.

Dont forget to add your own functionality for next and prev that adjusts each slide progression distance according to the width of the slides in the slider.

Also see here:

[How to make a image slider responsive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807755/how-to-make-a-image-slider-responsive)

And this is a good tutorial with somewhat quality code used. The slide comes out usable as well!

http://www.barrelny.com/blog/building-a-jquery-slideshow-plugin-from-scratch/

Hope this helps!

UPDATE:

Since the OP stated that the issue is with the js I dug up a simple slider I wrote a while back, here is the javascript/jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $.fn.someCustomSlider = function (autoplay, velocity){
    var sliderProps = [
      // props n methods, accessible through data-slider-* attributes
      { 
        settings : { 
          invokeBecause : $('[data-widget~="slider"]'),
          autoplay : autoplay,
          speed : velocity,
        },
        bindings : {
          slideRail : $('[data-function~="slide-rail"]'),
          nextButton : $('[data-function~="next"]'),
          prevButton : $('[data-function~="prev"]'),
          playButton : $('[data-function~="play"]'),
          pauseButton : $('[data-function~="pause"]'),
          stopButton : $('[data-function~="stop"]')
          // attach this functionality to the DOM

        },
        methods : {
          slideNext :  function(){          slideRail.animate({left: '-=100%'}, velocity)   },
          slidePrev : function(){ slideRail.animate({left: '+=100%'}, velocity)  },
          slideRestart : function(){ slideRail.animate({left: '0%'}, velocity)  },
          pause :  function(){ window.sliderTimer = setInterval(slideNext, velocity) }
        }
      }
    ]
    $.each(sliderProps, function(){
      //    iterate through all of the slider objects properties
      window.SliderProps = this;
      // set slider props to be accessible to the global scope
    });
  // slider props stored as vars
  var slideRail = SliderProps.bindings.slideRail;
  var play = SliderProps.bindings.playButton;
  var next = SliderProps.bindings.nextButton;
  var prev = SliderProps.bindings.prevButton;
  var pause = SliderProps.bindings.pauseButton;
  var stop = SliderProps.bindings.stopButton;
  var i = 0;

  function slideNext(){
    var slideNext = SliderProps.methods.slideNext();
  }
  function slidePrev(){
    var slidePrev = SliderProps.methods.slidePrev();
  }
  function slideStop(){
    /*slideRail.stop(); */
    window.clearInterval( sliderTimer  )
  }
  function slideRestart(){
    var slidePrev = SliderProps.methods.slideRestart();
    slideRail.stop(); 
    window.clearInterval( sliderTimer  )
  }
  function autoPlay(){
   SliderProps.methods.pause() 
  }
  // elemen -> event delegation -> function()
  next.click(slideNext)
  prev.click(slidePrev)
  stop.click(slideRestart)
  pause.click(slideStop)
  play.click(autoPlay)
  } // close function slider()
  someCustomSlider(true, 1000);
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eytrh

This was a basic version that I eventually extended but for simplicity sake, this should be just perfect I imagine.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response and demo @AlphaG33k 

My problem lies with my jQuery function I understand the CSS change fine, but I'm not sure how to rewrite the function to still cycle through images without stopping etc not using the width of the image.

I'll have a proper look at those links, but should i be writing my code differently? Really new to jQ.

Comment: If you put your partially working code in a codepen demo it will be easier for the community to help you

Comment: Updated with  new demo and code that works similar to yours. You are on the right path, everyone starts out with code just like yours!

Comment: Wow, thanks again for the demo and updates @AlphaG33k 

It works really well i'll try and implement this. Does it loop through when it gets to the final image? Very much appreciated!!

Comment: Sure, no problem teaching helps us learn. I actually feel bad because I would never write code like that now! But for learning purposes it should work. Sometimes the better the module the hard the source is to under stand. No it doesnt have the repeat built in but that is not that hard. You count the number of slides inside of the .slide container and then when the amount of next() firing or clicks reaches the amount of child slides then you know to reset the CSS back to left: 0 or whatever you wish. Don't forget to accept my answer if you like it by clicking the checkmark :)

Answer (score 0):

When working with responsive design, thinking in terms of pixels is a bad practice.

Give your slider and each slide a width of 100vw instead of 607px. That would make it equivalent to one "viewport width". In your JavaScript try modifying the `width` variable to be the string 100vw as well. Make sure to include the unit.

For more information on CSS units refer   [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length).

Comment: VW has sketchy browser support I wouldn't recommend getting into that mess just yet in a production site/app. IE still doesn't support much of the standard see here http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units plus no android support in 4.2, 4.3! How about using good old % points for old time sake.

Comment: Browser support is solid enough for me to feel comfortable. Percents work, but it depends on the elements position on the page. If I were building a modular system I would use vw.